# Allow app to terminate while sheet is visible

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a sheet that attaches to my main window. This is a login sheet that should not allow any interaction with the app until it is finished (modal as is the default). HOWEVER, I would like the user to be able to terminate the app. IE, they realize they need a login, give up and want to close the app. The default behavior is to play NSBeep and keep running. How can I override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `endSheet:` right after showing the sheet, it will give the behavior I'm looking for.

```
[NSApp beginSheet:self._loginController.window
   modalForWindow:self.window
    modalDelegate:nil
   didEndSelector:nil
      contextInfo:NULL];
[NSApp endSheet:self._loginController.window];
```

This does not dismiss the sheet, and when you are done, you can hide the sheet with `[window orderOut:nil];`.

Answer (score 7):

Beginning with 10.6 you can control whether the modal sheet should prevent the application from terminating. This should do it:

```
[myModalSheet setPreventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the root of the problem is that you're relying on the sheet to prevent interaction with the rest of the app. You're effectively storing application state information (logged in/not logged in) in a view, and that's not a good plan.

The sheet should allow the user to enter their login information, and the login sheet's controller should update the app's state as the info is entered. If you take this approach, the application won't allow the user to do anything that requires a login until the login process is actually complete, whether the sheet is there or not.

Comment: That's not the problem at all. It's not that interacting with the rest of the app would be destructive, it would just be unproductive and possibly confusing.

Comment: Okay. Consider calling `-setPreventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal:NO` on the sheet, then.

Comment: I wish there was a way to mark Caleb's comment as the accepted fix. That is exactly the function I needed. (And incidentally, one of the main reasons to allow it is because without it, your app will prevent the shutdown process from completing)